# Is this a valid proof of the Quotient rule?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

In an emergency in high-school, I once derived the quotient rule from the chain and product rules. I now wonder whether this was actually a valid proof. I reconstructed it as well as I could remember:

**Product Rule:**

$(fg)' = f'g + g'f$

**Chain Rule:**

$(f . g)' = f'(g) \cdot g'$

**Proof**

WTS $\left(\frac g h\right)' = \frac{g'h - h'g}{h^2}$

Let $f = \frac g h$. Then $f' = \left(\frac g h\right)' = (g \cdot h^{-1})' = (g') \cdot (h^{-1}) + (h^{-1})'(g)$ by the product rule.

Thus $f' = \frac{g'}{h} + (h^{-1})(g)$.

Remark that $h^{-1} = i(h)$ where $i(y) = y^{-1}$. By the chain rule, $(i(h))' = i'(h)\cdot (h')$. And if $i(y) = y^{-1}$, then $i'(y) = -y^{-2}$.

Thus $(h^{-1})' = -(h^{-2}) \cdot h' = \frac {-h'}{h^2}$.

So $f' = \frac {g'}{h} + \frac{-h'g}{h^2} = \frac{g'h - h'g}{h^2}$.

Is this valid? Note that I am aware of the existence of other, valid proofs of this. I am asking about this proof. I'm specifically hung up on whether letting $h^{-1} = i(h)$ holds. (Am I implicitly circumventing the variable with respect to which I am taking the derivative?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be valid although horribly confusing. First, usually in maths $h^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $h$, so this notation is not great. For example, let's say $f(x)=e^x$ then $f^{-1}(x)=\log x$, or $f(x)=\sin(x)$ then $f^{-1}(x)=\arcsin(x)$, etc. Also why do you interchange $f$ and $g$ and $h$ in this way? In the statement of the rule you use $f/g$ then you switch to $f=g/h$ in the proof.

Comment: Corrected statement of rule to avoid confusingly interchanging things. Not sure what you mean regarding notation.

Comment: Let's say $f(x)=e^x$ then $f^{-1}(x)=\log x$, or $f(x)=sin(x)$ then $f^{-1}(x)=arcsin(x)$, etc.

Comment: one should also remark that in the case $f(x)=e^x$, we have $(f(x))^{-1}=\frac{1}{e^x}$. So adding the argument here would make the notation clearer.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Ah, I see. Denoting multiplicative inverses of functions with $f^{-1}$ and denoting inverses of functions with $f^{-1}$ is only reasonable when dealing with certain functions, when the function inverse *is* the multiplicative inverse of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof of $(i(y))^{\prime }=\frac{-1}{y^{2}}$ which do not use the
quotient rule. In fact it uses the definition of the derivative
\begin{eqnarray*}
(i(y))^{\prime } &=&\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{i(y+h)-i(y)}{h}%
=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{1}{y+h}-\frac{1}{y}}{h} \\
&=&\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{y}{\left( y+h\right) y}-\frac{(y+h)}{%
(y+h)y}}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{y-(y+h)}{\left( y+h\right) y}}{h%
} \\
&=&\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{-h}{\left( y+h\right) y}}{h}%
=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{-h}{\left( y+h\right) y}\times \frac{1}{%
h} \\
&=&\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{-1}{\left( y+h\right) y}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}%
\frac{-1}{\left( y\right) y} \\
&=&\frac{-1}{y^{2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: thank you, that's helpful. Also, note that you should try not to submit multiple answers to the same question -- try to stick to one answer per question. This is not like a forum. You can edit your answers if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the product formula and you need that of the quotient, just put
the quotient equals to some new function, extract and apply the product
formula, like this
$$
w=\frac{u}{v}\rightarrow u=vw
$$
then
$$
u^{\prime }=(vw)^{\prime }=v^{\prime }w+vw^{\prime }
$$
therefore, 
$$
vw^{\prime }=u^{\prime }-v^{\prime }w=u^{\prime }-v^{\prime }\frac{u}{v}=%
\frac{u^{\prime }v-v^{\prime }u}{v}
$$
dividing by $v,$ yields
$$
w^{\prime }=\frac{u^{\prime }v-v^{\prime }u}{v^{2}}.\ \ Q.E.D.
$$

Comment: I'm familiar with this proof. Your effort is appreciated, but it does not answer my question, which is whether *my proof* is *valid*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You ask if your proof is correct. The hypothesis are: Product rule and Chain rule are supposed known and you want to proof the quotient rule. In your proof you have used some third matter which is not among your hypothsis, so you should proof it without using quotient rule to have the right to use it in your quotient rule proof. Your proof contains the word THEN two times, can you justify the second one without using the quotient-rule? THis is a usage of a particular quotient rule version. Your proof will be complete and correct when you prove that $(y^{-1})^{'}=-y^{-2}$ without using quotien trule. It is here the thing you looking for. [HOWEVER! if you did this proof when you was a student in calculus I or before, you deserves some congratulations (from me!) even if the proof is not acceptable in a rigor mathematical sense.]